# Group 2d array data by 2 columns to form a 3d associative array with summed column values in each group

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I have a 2d array with this data:

```
[
    [
        "totalTonne" => 11180,
        "wasteHierarchy" => "Disposal (Landfill)",
        "completionDate" => "2014-05-14"
    ],
    [
        "totalTonne" => 820,
        "wasteHierarchy" => "Energy Recovery",
        "completionDate" => "2014-06-14"
    ],
    [
        "totalTonne" => 21040,
        "wasteHierarchy" => "Energy Recovery",
        "completionDate" => "2014-08-14"
    ],
    [
        "totalTonne" => 7020,
        "wasteHierarchy" => "Energy Recovery",
        "completionDate" => "2014-11-14"
    ],
    [
        "totalTonne" => 6660,
        "wasteHierarchy" => "Recycling",
        "completionDate" => "2014-07-14"
    ],
    [
        "totalTonne" => 12000,
        "wasteHierarchy" => "Recycling",
        "completionDate" => "2014-09-14"
    ],
    [
        "totalTonne" => 8900,
        "wasteHierarchy" => "Recycling",
        "completionDate" => "2014-10-14"
    ],
    [
        "totalTonne" => 9100,
        "wasteHierarchy" => "Recycling",
        "completionDate" => "2014-12-14"
    ],
    [
        "totalTonne" => 5520,
        "wasteHierarchy" => "Recycling",
        "completionDate" => "2015-01-15"
    ],
    [
        "totalTonne" => 1900,
        "wasteHierarchy" => "Energy Recovery",
        "completionDate" => "2014-08-14"
    ],
    [
        "totalTonne" => 5950,
        "wasteHierarchy" => "Energy Recovery",
        "completionDate" => "2014-11-14"
    ],
    [
        "totalTonne" => 12000,
        "wasteHierarchy" => "Recycling",
        "completionDate" => "2014-07-14"
    ],
    [
        "totalTonne" => 10480,
        "wasteHierarchy" => "Recycling",
        "completionDate" => "2014-09-14"
    ],
    [
        "totalTonne" => 8900,
        "wasteHierarchy" => "Recycling",
        "completionDate" => "2014-10-14"
    ],
    [
        "totalTonne" => 10060,
        "wasteHierarchy" => "Recycling",
        "completionDate" => "2014-12-14"
    ],
    [
        "totalTonne" => 15500,
        "wasteHierarchy" => "Energy Recovery",
        "completionDate" => "2014-06-14"
    ],
    [
        "totalTonne" => 8850,
        "wasteHierarchy" => "Energy Recovery",
        "completionDate" => "2014-11-14"
    ]
]
```

I would like to convert it to a 3d array which groups by `wasteHierarchy` values on the first level, then `completionDate` values on the second level and then sums the `totalTonne` values in each group.

Desired output:

```
[Disposal (Landfill)] => Array
    (
        [May 14] => 11180
    )

[Energy Recovery] => Array
    (
        [Jun 14] => 16320
        [Aug 14] => 22940
        [Nov 14] => 21820
    )

[Recycling] => Array
    (
        [Jul 14] => 18660
        [Sep 14] => 22480
        [Oct 14] => 17800
        [Dec 14] => 19160
        [Jan 15] => 5520
    )
```

The PHP code I have, so far, is below:

```
$whmOutput = Array();
foreach($wasteHierMon as $whm) {
    $dateChanged = date("M y", strtotime($whm['completionDate']));

    $whmOutput_element = &$whmOutput[$dateChanged];
    $whmOutput_element['wasteHierarchy'] = $whm['wasteHierarchy'];
    $whmOutput_element['completionDate'] = $dateChanged;
    !isset($whmOutput_element['totalUom']) && $whmOutput_element['totalUom'] = 0;
    $whmOutput_element['totalUom'] += $whm['totalTonne'];

}
$newWHM = array();          
foreach($whmOutput as $whm) {
    $dateChanged = $whm['completionDate'];

    $wasteHierarchy = $whm['wasteHierarchy'];
    $totalUom = +$whm['totalUom'];

    $newWHM[$wasteHierarchy][$dateChanged] = $totalUom;
}
```

However, that code doesn't do the job properly. While it creates the structure I'm after, but it doesn't rearrange the data properly. It doesn't group the dates correctly and, because of this, the `totalTonne` value with that isn't correct.

How can I amend the code in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Qt2mH)

```
$whmOutput = array();
foreach ($wasteHierMon as $whm) {
    $dateChanged = date("M y", strtotime($whm['completionDate']));
     // if not defined, define with value zero
    if (!isset($whmOutput[$whm['wasteHierarchy']][$dateChanged])) {
        $whmOutput[$whm['wasteHierarchy']][$dateChanged] = 0;
    }
    // addition will always work now
    $whmOutput[$whm['wasteHierarchy']][$dateChanged] += $whm['totalTonne'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who prefer to return the result from functional iteration, `array_reduce()` is the ideal choice because the result array is not guaranteed to have the same count as the input array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FvClD))

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        $array,
        function($result, $row) {
            $group = date("M y", strtotime($row['completionDate']));
            $result[$row['wasteHierarchy']][$group] = ($result[$row['wasteHierarchy']][$group] ?? 0) + $row['totalTonne'];
            return $result;
        }
    )
);
```

---

To show an alternative to @charlietfl's answer, I'll demonstrate a `foreach()` with array destructuring syntax to enjoy convenient individual variables in the loop body. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VPPjC))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as ['totalTonne' => $total, 'wasteHierarchy' => $cat, 'completionDate' => $date]) {
    $group = date("M y", strtotime($date));
    $result[$cat][$group] = ($result[$cat][$group] ?? 0) + $total;
}
var_export($result);
```